# Session data is received NULL from one method to another method asp.net core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-core-3.1, session-state

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web API Application. I am trying to store the string value in session, when call the method that is set string in Session from client side it' fine and stored the value, but when I call another method for Get String from session that is null. please help me to fixe it.

**Startup ConfigureServices:**

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "AdventureWorks.Session";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true; // make the session cookie Essential
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddMvc();
   }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        app.UseAbp(options => { options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = false; }); 

        app.UseCors(_defaultCorsPolicyName); // Enable CORS!

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAbpRequestLocalization();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints();
  }
```

**method for set String:**

```
 public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetCaptchaImage()
 {  

        Captcha.Captcha captcha = new Captcha.Captcha();
        int width = 100;
        int height = 36;
        var captchaCode = captcha.GenerateCaptchaCode();
        var result = captcha.GenerateCaptchaImage(width, height, captchaCode);
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("CaptchaCode", result.CaptchaCode);
        Stream s = new MemoryStream(result.CaptchaByteData);
        return new FileStreamResult(s, "image/png");
   }
```

**method for GetString:**

```
 public bool ValidateCaptchaCode(string userInputCaptcha)
    {
        var captchaValueInSession = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext..GetString("CaptchaCode");
        var isValid = userInputCaptcha == captchaValueInSession;
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Remove("CaptchaCode");
        return isValid;
    }
```

**Is NULL**

```
var captchaValueInSession = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("CaptchaCode");
```

*how can I get Session value from another method*

Answer (score -1):

can also validate captcha in frontend rather in` api

```
string rr = HttpContext.Session.GetString("CaptchaCode");
                if (model.captchacode != rr)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Enter Valid Captcha");
                }
```

Comment: validation of captcha can also done on front end rather in api